# Posting JSON to ASP.NET web service (ASMX) only getting as far as OPTION and not full POST

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, web-services, iis

I have been working on a JQuery script that posts JSON to my asp.net web service. If the script is on the same domain it processes correctly but when I try to run the script from a local file or on an alternative domain not appears to happen to the eye!.. Though what I have noticed is that within my web logs the attempt is reaching the server but with the method OPTIONS rather than POST.

I have tried to set the following headers within IIS, web.config directly and within my global.asax file to on the application_beginRequest event but no success thus far!

Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET, POST.

My global.asax file contain this:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

    EnableCrossDmainAjaxCall();
}

private void EnableCrossDmainAjaxCall()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                      "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                      "Content-Type, Accept");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age",
                      "1728000");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

My client side script is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            url: "http://myservice.mydomain.com/Data.asmx/Import",
            data: "{\"AppSession\":" + JSON.stringify(session) + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                // Insert the returned HTML into the <div>.
                $('#content').html(data.d);
            },
            error: function (j, t, e) {

                $('#content').html(e);
            }
        });
```

My web service code is as follows...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for DataMgt
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "DataManagement")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class DataMgt : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public DataMgt () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 

    }
    public class GeoData
    {
        public string GEOLongitude { get; set; }
        public string GEOLatitude { get; set; }
        public string GEOAccuracy { get; set; }
        public string GEOStatusID { get; set; }
    }

    public class AppSession
    {
        public GeoData GEOData { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public string CountryID { get; set; }
    }

    [WebMethod]

    public string ImportData(AppSession AppSession)
    {
        string strStatusCode;
        try
        {
            //Do stuff here with requested data

            strStatusCode = "SUCCESS";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            strStatusCode = "FAILURE";
        }

        return strStatusCode;

    } 
}
```

As I said earlier, this runs absolutely fine when the client side script is run on the same domain.

The website that hosts my service is on IIS 7 and ASP.NET 4.

Has anyone expereinced this when using a similar setup to me or can anyone suggest how to resolve this?

Many thanks in advance,

Rit

Comment: Can you watch your request in Fiddler or similar and verify there are no other headers you need on the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` line?

Comment: Thanks, I will try Fiddler... to be honest, I have never used it.

Comment: Hi

Here is raw headers from Fiddler...

OPTIONS /Data.asmx/Import HTTP/1.1
Host: myservice.mydomain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.51.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.1 Safari/534.51.22
Content-Length: 0
Accept: */*
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: file://
Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type, Accept
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive

Can you see anything wrong here at all?

Comment: How does the response look like?

Comment: I don't have my working CORS code to hand, sorry, but you could try adding `Content-Length, Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding, Connection` to the list anyway.

Comment: Maybe this one helps you: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control#Preflighted_requests
It shows all the steps in the request/response and how it should work. Use Fiddler and see if you missing something.

Comment: Thanks all. I will try your recommendations tomorrow morning ahem back at work.

Comment: Just before I left the office I was getting a debug error in safari regarding the origin being disallowed even though I am specifying Access-Control-Allow-Origin * within various places within my site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you working on diffrent domain you will not be able to POST request to your server. Its restricted, you have to use JSONP

JSONP:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

A tutorial:
http://abstractform.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/accessing-remote-asp-net-web-services-using-jsonp/

Comment: Hi,Are you sure that that is truly correct. I was under the understanding that if you set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to * then this will lift the restriction and enabnle JSON rather than JSONP.

Comment: I think its true to older browser. If i execute your code in the console in Chrome Fiddler shows that a request is sent. But if i execute the code in IE 9 it tells me, "Not allowed" and no request was possible, maybe the user can change the Security setting in someway.
http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/cross_origin_requests

Comment: Hi Simon, by adding all of the headers as per your webdavsystem.com link, this resolved my issue. many thanks indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's this simple, but when I try to make a cross domain .ajax() call with jQuery I have to append this to the url:

```
&jsoncallback=?
```

Comment: Ah-ha, I don't use that querystring with .ajax() (I just red Simon's post). I use it with .getJSON()

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a dataType of jsonp rather than json. Check the jQuery docs for the ajax method.

Comment: I am sure I should be able to use JSON but set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to * within my site.. JSONP is great but limited to a maxiumumcharacter count.